# jQuery ultrapassado?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou começando com Javascript e um amigo me falou que o jQuery está sendo deixado de lado, isso é verdade? Se sim, por que ele está sendo deixado de lado? Qual seria uma alternativa para jQuery?

Comment: Ops, não tinha visto :(

Comment: [Você não precisa do *jQuery*](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Particularmente: acredito que jQuery é uma biblioteca grande, bem documentada, atualizada regularmente, rica em recursos e de fácil utilização... mas não vejo nela uma necessidade sobre o JavaScript e seus recursos nativos do navegador, então sempre acabo utilizando apenas JavaScript; porém é opnião pessoal, se você olhar o mercado jQuery ainda é bastante utilizado

Comment: Eu gosto do jQuery, facilita bastante a vida.

Comment: Eu também gosto muito, fiquei muito assustado e quando fui pesquisar na internet e vi o pessoal falando que estava ficando de lado. Sou membro novo da comunidade, legal ver que o pessoal aqui é bastante ativo, eu já usava aqui para pesquisar alguns erros, mas agora membro oficial. :)

Comment: Pode ficar sossegado, jQuery é igual PHP, são os patinho feio, mas que não vão desaparecer nunca.